# Nature of singularity and value of residue

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

I want to come to know the type of singularity of the complex function $f(z)= (e^{(1/z)})/\sin z$ at $z=0$. 
For $e^{(1/z)}$ the limit at $0$ does not exist. And also $sin z$ approaches $0$ when $z$ tends to $0$. Could this singularity be a pole despite non-existence of limit of function in the numerator? If it is not a pole then could we still talk about its residue? If I consider this singularity a pole of order $1$and evaluate the limit $zf(z)$ as $z$ tends to $0$, I end up with the limit of$e^{(1/z)}$ as $z$ tends to $0$ which does not exist. Now I am stuck. I tried using Laurent series expansions but that seemed daunting to me. How do I calculate residue for this function in a relatively quick manner?

Comment: You have determined $\lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \mathrm{e}^{1/z}$ does not exist.  How about, for real $x$, $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^-} \mathrm{e}^{1/x}$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \mathrm{e}^{1/x}$.  What kind of singularity can do that?

Comment: For former case, limit is $0$ while for the latter, it is $\infty$. This led me to conclude that the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: if $f(z)$ has a pole of order $n$ at $z=0$, and $g(z)$ has a zero of order $m$ at $z=0$, then what does $f(z) g(z)$ have at $z=0$?  Could it be an essential singularity?

As to the other question you mentioned: yes, it is quite possible to talk about a residue for an essential singularity.

Comment: In this case $f(z)= e^{1/z}$ has essential singularity at $z=0$ i.e. a pole of infinite order while $g(z)= 1/sin z$ has a simple pole at $z=0$. So does this mean $f(z)g(z)$ is a pole of infinite order or in other words, an essential singularity?

Comment: But how can we find residue somewhat quickly?

Comment: No, in this case $f(z) = e^{1/z}/\sin(z)$ and $g(z) = \sin(z)$.  If it was not an essential singularity (please don't call it "a pole of infinite order", there's no such thing), it would be either a pole or a removable singularity.  Neither is possible, because $f(z) g(z)$ has an essential singularity.

Comment: To find the residue, you need Laurent series of $e^{1/z}$ and $1/\sin(z)$. Since the latter does not have a closed form, I don't think there's a closed form for the residue.

Comment: What can we say about the singularity of function $sin z/ (z^3)$ at $z=0$? Is it pole of order 2? I have constructed this question taking $f(z)$ as having a pole of order 3 and $g(z)$ having a simple zero at $z=0$.

Comment: Yes, $\sin(z)$ has a zero of order $1$ and $z^3$ has a zero of order $3$, so $\sin(z)/z^3$ has a pole of order $3-1=2$.